# Extract JSON data in Presto SQL query

Tags: sql, json, database, presto, trino

I have 3 columns in my table.
ID, assignee, comments
comments column is in json format like following

[{"author": "a", "timestamp": "2022-11-22T21:43:51Z"}, {"author": "b", "timestamp": "2022-11-22T22:56:03Z"},............]

I am trying to extract the data from table but getting NULL values.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    assignee, 
    ID,
    CAST(json_extract(comments,'$.comments') AS ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>) 
    AS ticket_commenters_with_timestamp 
  FROM 
    table1
```

It is giving me NULL in the last column.

I am expecting the following result:

ID.      assignee.      author.      timestamp

1. ```
     Andrew.        a.           2022-08-17T14:01:16Z
   ```
2. ```
     Andrew.        b.           2022-08-17T14:01:18Z
   ```

Can anyone please help me and let me know what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not a json object, it is a json array, and it does have `comments` property. You need to process it as json array, and use `unnest` if you want to flatten it. For example:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(assignee, ID, comments) AS (
 values ('Andrew', 1, json '[{"author": "a", "timestamp": "2022-08-17T14:01:16Z"}, {"author": "b", "timestamp": "2022-08-17T14:01:18Z"}]')
)

-- query
select ID,
    assignee,
    json_extract(m, '$.author') as author,
    json_extract(m, '$.timestamp') as timestamp
from dataset,
unnest(cast(comments as array(json))) as t(m);
```

Output:

| ID | assignee | author | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andrew | a | 2022-08-17T14:01:16Z |
| 1 | Andrew | b | 2022-08-17T14:01:18Z |

P.S.

Use `json_parse` if `comments` column is varchar and not json.